# Скопировать из строки s, начиная с m символа, n символов

Tags: c++

мне нужно скопировать из строки s, начиная с m символа, n символов, при этом ввод строки осуществляется через вектор в котором я указываю количество строк.
И мне нужна помощь в реализации первой части задания.
Вот мой код, который пока что получилось реализовать

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string b;
    int j;
    cin >> j;
    vector <string> vector_first(j);

    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        string b;
        cin >> b;
        cout << vector_first[i]<< b << " ";
    }

}
```

Вывод:

```
5
privet kak tvoi dela Diana  
privet kak tvoi dela Diana
```

Comment: Хм... Не приходило в голову, что для копирования строки может использоваться string.copy?

Comment: @MBo Попробовал вот так, но не компилируется     size_t length = b.copy(vector_first, 3, 3);
    vector_first[length] = '\0';
    cout <<  vector_first << '\n';
    return 0;

Comment: vector_first.copy - копирование элементов **не строки, а вектора**, и куда - в число? Просто задумайтесь, что нужно сделать.

Comment: Так, я поменял vector_first.copy на b.copy, и size_t на string, но теперь ошибка в том что мне нужно преобразовать vector_first который  находиться в (vector_first, 3, 3) к char или я просто неправильно задаю параметры?

Comment: Посмотрел string.copy, там не тот результат, привел ответ с substr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vector_first[i] = b.substr(m,n);
```